# Why is my browser blocking use of my camera and microphone?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, zoom-meeting

I've just installed Windows 10 on a laptop and I'm having an issue with the microphone and camera not working from the web browser. This issue has occurred when trying to connect online services which use the camera such as Zoom.

I will see this popup alerting me to the issue:

[image]

There are links to guides on how to solve this but everything is already set to permissive. For example, on the same page where I am blocked I also see this message confirming that access is NOT blocked:

[image]

Windows privacy settings are also permissive and are not blocking:

[image]

[image]

I know that both the camera and microphone work fine on this laptop. The issue is that they are not working in my browser. I have no problem using Zoom when connected through their downloadable software.

I have tried both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Both are blocking.

Why are my browsers failing to access my microphone and camera?

Comment: You have allowed desktop applications access to your camera?  Are you by chance trying to do this while the Zoom application is running?

Comment: The Zoom application wasn't even installed. I only installed it after giving up at trying to make things work in the browser.

Comment: If you use a fresh Chrome profile does it work?  You should backup your current profile